# Visual Studio 2015 Web API 2 Project hanging

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

For someone reason when I open a solution that contains a specific Web API 2.0 project it is causing Visual Studio 2015 to hang.  When I remove the project folder the solution will open correctly.  I have confirmed that visual studio does not hang when opening any other Web API 2 projects, so something has to be corrupted with this project, but I am not sure what.  The error seems to have started occurring after merging about 400 unit tests with some code that added application insights so I don't know if that could cause something like this.

[image]

Things I have tried:

1) Clearing out caches under appdata.

2) Removing all packages and reloading them

3) Deleting the git folder that the solution is in and re-cloning it.

4) Deleting Bin / Obj folders

5) Restarting the computer multiple times

6) Updating every extension in visual studio and visual studio itself and my computer

7) Disabling all visual studio add-ons

8) Opening the solution disconnected from Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue was the packages were not lining up so what I did to fix this was changed all the packages in the packages.config file to be the same .Net version net461 and then deleted my packages folder and redownloaded the packages.